# Non associative array with numeric keys returns length 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-promise

I want to loop over an array `$scope.todos`

```
for (var i = $scope.todos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   console.log($scope.todos[i]);
};
```

But `$scope.todos.length` returns `0`.

```
$scope.todos
```

looks like this:

[image: array]

What am I doing wrong? I think this is not an associative array? The indexes are numbers? It doesn't return `undefined`, just 0. Thanks for any help.

Edit: more code

```
'use strict';

angular.module('todos')

.controller('TodosController', ['$scope', '$location', '$state',      '$stateParams', 'Todos',
function($scope, $location, $state, $stateParams, Todos) {

    console.log($scope.todos);
    console.log($scope.todos.length);

    function calculateDayAygoForTodos(){
        //foreach todo in todos
            for (var i = $scope.todos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                console.log("todos length");
                    console.log($scope.todos[i]);
            };


     }
```

**Solution:**
The problem was the async nature of the functions, I was trying to call the `$scope.todos.length` before the todos were loaded. Solved with a simple delay using `timeOut` function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log($scope.todos.length);
}, 1000);
```

Might not be optimal solution, but now I don't get ùndefined`anymore, but the length of the array. Thanks to War10ck for pointing this out.

Comment: When/where/how is `$scope.todos` being created/populated/loaded?

Comment: show more code, like where you log `$scope.todos`, and where you construct it

Comment: It looks like it may be a `promise` object. Promises are commonly used with async operations. It could be that your `for` loop operation is running before the action is completed and `$scope.todos` is populated...

Comment: Seems plausible. But `console.log($scope.todos)` DOES return a full array, just the `.length` function returns 0.

Comment: DevTools may update the object on the console later. I bet you should see an empty array if you set a break point at `console.log($scope.todos)`.

Comment: @Harbinger, if you try `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.todos))` you can see state in stringify moment, so it will be empty array, possibly with utility promise properties

Comment: @Harbinger also try see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync)

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that the length property is not set.

@steppefox (in his answer) has a good and trusted way of iterating the array.

Another way to iterate over the array is to use lodash [forEach](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach) function, its similar but said to be better at performance.

Checkout lodash for other array operations as well. It has tons of it.

Answer (score -2):

You can loop over array or object with:

```
angular.forEach($scope.todos,function(item,index){

});
```